# Text to Column change as Text to row

Tags: excel, vba, text-to-column

Have some new data to workout with Text to rows format.

In normal we will use text delimiter in excel to split the data from one column.
I am in need of the same feature in row wise.

example
List of location in a column.

```
CHARLESTON, JACKSONVILLE, BALTIMORE, NEW YORK, NORFOLK, SAVANNAH
CHARLESTON, JACKSONVILLE, BALTIMORE, NEW YORK, NORFOLK, SAVANNAH
HOUSTON, MOBILE, NEW ORLEANS
HOUSTON, MOBILE, NEW ORLEANS
PORT EVERGLADES
```

Expected Result :

Source Data Expected result

```
 CHARLESTON
 JACKSONVILLE
 BALTIMORE
 NEW YORK
 NORFOLK
 SAVANNAH
```

Kindly help me with a vba code for the same.

Thanks
[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4SZJO.jpg)

- Sample file updated :

[Excel](http://www.filedropper.com/sample_2)

Comment: You could just split those rows into an array and print them to the worksheet. Run it in a loop to print each row in its own column.

Comment: split as normal then unpivot?

Comment: Or you could just use `Text to Columns` as usual then copy the range and `Paste Special` >> `Transpose` to avoid VBA altogether. :-)

Comment: Instructions on unpivot: http://superuser.com/questions/78439/is-it-possible-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel

Comment: text to columns then transpose it?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this Sub:

```
Sub TextToRows(txt As String, targetRng As Range)
    Dim arr As Variant

    arr = Split(Replace(txt, " ", ""), ",")
    targetRng.Resize(UBound(arr) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arr)
End Sub
```

to be called from your main code as follows:

```
TextToRows Range("A1").Text, Range("B1") '<--| write the content of cell "A1" from cell "B1" downwards
```

Comment: Thanks for your input........ Getting near as needed. Updated the source data and result reported... please help

Comment: I gave you the code to fulfill the requested _"Text to Column change as Text to row"_ you asked for and as per your linked example, too. You may then want to accept my answer. While for further issues you should made a new post showing your coding efforts

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TextToRows(MyRange As Range)

Dim MyArray As Variant
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Integer

i = 0
For Each r In MyRange
    MyArray = Split(WorksheetFunction.Trim(r), ", ")
    Range("B1").Offset(0, i).Resize(UBound(MyArray) + 1, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(MyArray)
    i = i + 1
Next r

End Sub

Sub RunTest()
    TextToRows Range("A1:A5")
End Sub
```

It only works for data in the first five rows of column A and prints to columns B and beyond. But you can modify it. :-)